# function and pointers

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a program that would convert celcius to fahrenheit and visa-versa. My program is compiling, but it gives me wrong results. I'm been trying to change it by changing pointers, but it wouldnt work. Can anyone please point out to me what is my problem? It seems to me it's in declarations and pointers, but i'm not sure.Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>

float f2c(float f);
float c2f(float c);

int main(void)
{
 float cel;
 float celcius;
 float fahren;
 float fah;
 char ch;
 float number;

scanf("%c %f", &ch, &number);

if(&ch == "-f"){
  f2c(number);
  celcius=f2c(number);
  printf("%f", celcius);
  }

 else{
  c2f(number);
  fahren = c2f(number);
  printf("%f", fahren);
  }

return 0;
}

float f2c(float f)
{
 float cel = (f - 32) * 5/9;
 return cel;
} 

float c2f(float c)
{
 float fah = (9 * c/5 + 32);
 return fah;
}
```

Comment: You should use the debugger to step through your program line-by-line; this will enable you to inspect what decisions it's making, and what the values of intermediate variables are.  Alternatively, you could add lots of print statements to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use floating-point arithmetic, not integer arithmetic, because in integer arithmetic, 5/9 is 0.   So you could make this change to your code (though `float` parameters are unusual):

```
float f2c(float f)
{
 return  (f - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0;
} 

float c2f(float c)
{
 return 9.0 * c/5.0 + 32.0;
}
```

Also as one of the other answers states, the condition `(&ch == "-f")` is never true.

Here is a complete working example, with error checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

static double f2c(double f)
{
 return (f - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0;
} 

static double c2f(double c)
{
 return 9.0 * c/5.0 + 32.0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i;
 const char *label_f = "Fahrenheit";
 const char *label_c = "Celcius";
 const char *from, *to;
 double (*conversion)(double);

 from = label_c;
 to = label_f;
 conversion = c2f;

 for (i=1; i<argc; ++i)
   {
     if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "-f"))
       {
         from = label_f;
         to = label_c;
         conversion = f2c;
       }
     else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "-c"))
       {
         from = label_c;
         to = label_f;
         conversion = c2f;
       }
     else
       {
         char *suffix = NULL;
         double temp_in;

         errno = 0;
         temp_in = strtod(argv[i], &suffix);

         if (ERANGE == errno)
           {
             if (HUGE_VAL == temp_in) 
               {
                 fprintf(stderr, "%s is too big", argv[i]);
                 return 1;
               }
             else
               {
                 assert(-HUGE_VAL == temp_in);
                 fprintf(stderr, "%s is too small", argv[i]);
                 return 1;
               }
           }
         else if (errno != 0 && (suffix == argv[i]))
           {
             /* no conversion was performed. */
             fprintf(stderr, "%s is not a number", argv[i]);
             return 1;
           }
         else if (*suffix) 
           {
             fprintf(stderr, "Expected a number but saw '%s'\n", argv[i]);
             return 1;
           }
         else
           {
             const double temp_out = (*conversion)(temp_in);
             printf("%f %s is %f %s.\n", temp_in, from, temp_out, to);
           }
       }
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Odd that this was voted down, but nobody bothered to explain why.

Answer (score 3):

`if(&ch == "-f")` this is the problem.
It should be :

`if(ch == 'f')`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing char with a C-string `"-f"`. Use `strcmp` to compare C-strings.

You may also have declare `ch` as char array to more than one character which you need here. Because, you can't store "-f" in a single char as you do now.

With the changes:

```
#include<stdio.h>

float f2c(float f);
float c2f(float c);

int main(void)
{
 float cel;
 float celcius;
 float fahren;
 float fah;
 char ch[25];
 float number;

scanf("%s %f", ch, &number);

if(strcmp(ch,"-f")==0){
  f2c(number);
  celcius=f2c(number);
  printf("%f", celcius);
  }

 else{
  c2f(number);
  fahren = c2f(number);
  printf("%f", fahren);
  }

return 0;
}

float f2c(float f)
{
 float cel = (f - 32) * 5/9.0;
 return cel;
} 

float c2f(float c)
{
 float fah = (9 * c/5.0 + 32);
 return fah;
}
```

This is essentially your code, but modified it to read the input as C-string.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:

You are doing needless calls to the conversion functions and throwing away the results, just before doing the same calls again but with proper handling of the return value:

```
if(&ch == "-f"){
  f2c(number);  /* This line does absolutely nothing! */
  celcius=f2c(number);
  printf("%f", celcius);
  }
```